# What is the best way to call a handling function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading the [ReactJs documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) about **Handling events** and I wondered what the best practice is for calling a handling function in a component.

My question is very simple (and even basic I think): what should be used between `onClick={handleClick}` or `onClick={this.handleClick]` ?

I wonder after seeing these two pieces of code in which `handleClick` is called without the keyword `this` in the first code and with in the second code.

```js
ActionLink() {
  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('The link was clicked.');
  }

  return (
    <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me
    </a>
  );
}
```

```js
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: They are both different. The first example is a functional component, whereas the second example is a class based component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are 2 different situations.

- `onClick={handleClick}` is used in functional component, in a function `this` key work is refer to the place when the function is call, you don't use `this` in functional component.
- `onClick={this.handleClick]` is used in class component. In class you need to use `this` key work to access class property which is function in this case.